# Change background color of div over time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this in my css for the div:

```
div {
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-animation-name: colorChange;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 100s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorChange {
  0% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

the only problem is I need the div to stay red after the transition is complete, and not go back to the initial white color afterward. Any suggestions OR even a better way to accomplish this in jquery?

I would actually really like to say "change to yellow after 5 minutes, change to red after another 5 minutes and stay red" instead of having a transition like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `animation-fill-mode:forwards`

> [**animation-fill-mode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)
>
> The animation-fill-mode CSS property specifies how a CSS animation should apply styles to its target before and after its execution.
>
> "**forwards**"
>
> The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution. The last keyframe depends on the value of animation-direction and animation-iteration-count:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background-color: white;
  animation-name: colorChange;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorChange {
  0% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```